# xpath based on condition in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an xml of the following structure:

```
<Root>
  <Sample>
    <Materil material_class="book" />
    <Book Name="harry" Price="8" />
    <Book Name="small things" Price="9" />
    <Book Name="snow" Price="10" />
  </Sample>
 <Commodity>
    <Sample>
        <Materil material_class="sub" />
        <Book Name="sherin" Price="8" />
        <Book Name="bigthings" Price="9" />
        <Book Name="leopard" Price="10" />
    </Sample>
    <Commodity>
         <Sample>
            <Materil material_class="sub" />
            <Book Name="azxcv" Price="86" />
            <Book Name="ddddd" Price="79" />
            <Book Name="qwert" Price="810" />
         </Sample>
    </Commodity>
    <Commodity>
         <Sample>
            <Materil material_class="subtwo" />
            <Book Name="ratnam" Price="86" />
            <Book Name="shantharam" Price="99" />
            <Book Name="da vinci" Price="10" />
         </Sample>
    </Commodity>
 </Commodity>
</Root>
```

Is there a way to iterate this xml based on condition like,if the `material_class = "sub"`, iterate the `Book` tag below that and store the `@Name` and `@Price` . If the `material_class = "book"`, iterate the `Book` tag below that. Also i want to get the length of number of `/Root/Commodity/Commodity` tags (in this case , it is two). Any help is appreciated. I am new to XPath.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Book `@Name` and `@Price` for `@material_class='sub'` or `@material_class='book'`, use this XPATH

```
/Root[descendant-or-self::Sample or Sample[descendant-or-self::*]]//*[Materil[@material_class='sub' or @material_class='book']]/Book
```

**OR**

```
//Sample[Materil[@material_class='book' or @material_class='sub']]/Book
```

After loading this XPATH, to print the Name use `@Name` and Price use `@Price`

To get the length of number of /Root/Commodity/Commodity tags, XPATH is

```
/Root/Commodity/Commodity
```

**OR**

```
//Commodity/Commodity
```

### JAVA:

```
NodeList node = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/Root/Commodity/Commodity", xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
count = node.getLength(); // OUTPUTS: 2
```

*For your information, actually rendering XML through XSLT is much better performance and easier to implement.*

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Sample[Materil[@material_class='sub']]/Book"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Sample[Materil[@material_class='book']]/Book"/>
```

I do not have access to an XSL editor right now, so have not tested the above, but it will give you an idea. Select the Book, and constrain the Materil with the condition you want.

Comment: This is an xslt template i believe. I have to achieve this using java

Comment: ah.. then use DOM traversal.. follow this example
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/org.w3c.dom/xpath_GetElemByAttr.html